# Whats the best redundancy setup on AWS for SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, disaster-recovery, database-mirroring

We're migrating our environment over to AWS from a colo facility. As part of that we are upgrading our 2 SQL Server 2005s to 2014s. The two are currently mirrored and we'd like to keep it that way or find other ways to make the servers redundant.  # of transactions/server-use is light for our app - but it's in production, requires high availability, and, as a result, requires some kind of fail over.

We have already setup one EC2 instance and put SQL server 2014 on it (as opposed to using RDBMS for licensing reasons and are now exploring what to do next to achieve this.

What suggestions do people have to achieve the redundancy we need?

I've seen two options thus far from here and googling around. I list them below - we're very open to other options!

First, use RDBMS mirroring service, but I can't tell if that only applies if the principal server is also RDBMS - it also doesn't help with licensing.

Second, use multiple availability zones.  What are the pros/cons of this versus using different regions altogether (e.g., bandwidth issues) etc? And does multi-AZ actually give redundancy (if AWS goes down in Oregon, for example, then doesn't everything go down)?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: AWS inter-region links are very large bandwidth with very low latencies. You should not have problems by running multi-az. In fact, most AWS best practices will recommend you to be running multi-az where possible.

Comment: Super-helpful, thanks.  Any suggestions on how to implement?

Comment: you dont need much different to local network configuration to aws one.
I have configured mssql in mirror mode before, only catch is mirror failover/fallback was very frequent. (more than few times a day).
you need to use 3rd mssql as a witness server which may be a licensing headache. I have read somewhere that ms wont charge for witness licensing but never verified it with MS.

if $ isnt problem, i would recommend setting up DAG, with mssql enterprise. its far more reliable and "always on", with both nodes as active-active. 
https://aws.amazon.com/windows/resources/whitepapers/alwayson/

Answer (score 1):

The **Multi-AZ capability of Amazon RDS** (Relational Database Service) is designed to offer high-availability for a database.

From [Amazon RDS Multi-AZ Deployments](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/details/multi-az/):

> When you provision a **Multi-AZ DB Instance**, Amazon RDS automatically creates a primary DB Instance and **synchronously replicates** the data to a standby instance in a **different Availability Zone** (AZ). Each AZ runs on its own physically distinct, independent infrastructure, and is engineered to be highly reliable. In case of an infrastructure failure (for example, instance hardware failure, storage failure, or network disruption), Amazon RDS performs an **automatic failover to the standby**, so that you can resume database operations as soon as the failover is complete. Since the endpoint for your DB Instance remains the same after a failover, your application can resume database operation without the need for manual administrative intervention.

**Multiple Availability Zones** are recommended to improve availability of systems. Each AZ is a separate physical facility such that any disaster that should befall one AZ should not impact another AZ. This is normally considered **sufficient redundancy** rather than having to run across multiple Regions. It also has the benefit that **data can be synchronously replicated between AZs due to low-latency connections**, while this might not be possible between Regions since they are located further apart.

One final benefit... The Multi-AZ capability of Amazon RDS can be activated by simply selecting "Yes" when the database is launched. Running your own database and using mirroring services requires you to do considerably more work on an on-going basis.

Comment: Thanks, however, does this work if you are implementing an EC2 instance and installing SQL server on top of it? Again, we're doing it this way for licensing reasons.  I'm assuming it doesn't, so what are the alternatives?

Comment: The automatic Multi-AZ capabilities mentioned above are only provided when using Amazon RDS. If you are installing and running the database yourself, then you must configure any backup/failure capabilities yourself. Using multiple AZs is better than multi-region due to lower latency connections (AZs are very close to each other within one region).

Comment: thanks John - sounds like thats what we'll do. Any gotchas we should be aware of otherwise?